# Java- issue calling instances of methods?

Tags: java, class

I created a class that's designed to take 2 fractions, each with a numerator and denominator and add them, outputting another fraction.

When I compile the program I get an issue involving:

*Fraction F3 = new Fraction.add (F1, F2);* In the main method

The error: *Type Fraction$add was not found*

If I make everything one class the program will run but I want all the methods to be strictly in the Fraction class and calling the fractions in the UseFraction class.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;


public final class Fraction
{
    private int numerator, denominator;

    public Fraction (int numerator, int denominator) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        this.numerator = numerator;

        if (denominator == 0)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ();
        }
        this.denominator = denominator;
    }


    //As an instance method
    public void add (Fraction F)
    {
        this.numerator = this.numerator * F.denominator + this.denominator * F.numerator;
        this.denominator = this.numerator * this.denominator;
    }


    //As a static method
    public static Fraction add (Fraction F1, Fraction F2)
    {
        return new Fraction (F1.numerator * F2.denominator + F1.denominator * F2.numerator, F1.numerator);
    }


    //@ Override
    public String toString ()
    {
        return (this.numerator + "/" + this.denominator);
    }

}



public class UseFraction 
{

    public static void main (String str[]) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));

        Fraction F1 = new Fraction (5, 7); // first fraction constructor
        Fraction F2 = new Fraction (3, 8); // second fraction constructor
        Fraction F3 = new Fraction.add (F1, F2); // addition

        System.out.println ("The sum is " + F3); 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Fraction.add(F1, F2)`, not `new Fraction.add`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Fraction F3 = new Fraction.add (F1, F2); // addition
```

Should this be just:

```
Fraction F3 = Fraction.add (F1, F2); // addition
```

?

Answer (score 0):

```
Fraction F3 = new Fraction.add (F1, F2);
```

Change it to:

```
Fraction F3 = Fraction.add (F1, F2);
```